# Time series database for use with Python/Pandas - what kind of DB am I looking for?

Tags: python, database, pytables

First of all, I know next to nothing about databases, so if the answer to my questions is "read a book on DBs", don't hesitate to tell me.

I have a large collection<sup>1</sup> of environmental time series data collected at a number of different sites around the world. All time series have different lengths (e.g. one site may have data for a year, another one for two years, etc.), but they are generally in the same format (same column headers; columns of variables that were not measured at a specific site are filled with N/A). In addition, meta data including site description, instruments used, etc. are available for every dataset.

What I would like to do is store these measurements in a database that I can easily access using Python. I would like to analyse them using Pandas, so it would be great if there was a way to make this work with data frames instead of arrays for each single column. It probably won't be much of a problem to store each column as indivudal arrays and construct data frames afterwards, though, if that makes more sense (for instance, to drop the N/A columns) and/or is easier to implement. Also, access speed has priority over file size.

It would be best to have a database that can work with queries like *"give me the `temperature` time series from all `grassland` sites"*, *"plot `wind speed` against `time of day` for all `European` measurements"*, and similar requests.

Of course I am not asking you for a complete solution, but I would be very grateful for some pointers into the right direction. What type of DB am I looking for? Is there something Python can work with? I was looking into PyTables, but I'm not exactly sure if it a hierarchical database suited for my tasks (or if anything else is anyway)? Thanks in advance.

<sup>1</sup>To be exact, I don't have it yet, but that's what I will work with in the near future. It's probably not what some of you would call "large collection". The whole DB needs to hold less than 1000 tables each with less than 100 columns and less than 100k rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using HDF5 for this.  It's a disk file format which supports hierarchies, arrays, metadata like comments, and more.  And it integrates very well with Python/NumPy via h5py and with Pandas via PyTables.  See here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-tools-text-csv-hdf5

Now, you may be saying "That's not a database!"  Of course it isn't.  But the example queries you gave, and my own experience with time series data, suggest that you don't need a traditional database system, because a lot of what you'll do with the data will occur on the client side, and the amount of data you want to store is possible to load into memory on commodity machines.

HDF5 supports compression (you may not want this if you only care about access speed).  It's easy to read from multiple languages, including C++, Python, R, and more.  It's also quite mature and battle-tested.

I'd consider storing each site's data in one file; this may make basic management tasks easier.  But HDF5 has an internal hierarchy as well if you prefer to have it all in a single file.  Depending on your access patterns you might make a different decision too, such as storing everything in a single file per month or so.  Once you try it out for a while you'll probably come to a good understanding of what layout makes the most sense.  There is also a tradeoff to be made with "chunking" if you will later add rows or columns (one or the other will be optimally efficient depending on how you store the data).

Comment: Thanks a lot, so pytables it is. I'm not really sure I understand everything in your last paragraph, though, (e.g. why not store it in one file?) but I suppose I will after a little bit of playing around with it?

Comment: Reasons to not store it in a single file might include making the files easier to back up, update, distribute, etc.  One giant file can be nice, or it can be unwieldy.  That's all up to you, and yes, you'll figure it out once you try it.